# Angular RxJS Subscribe to HTTP Request in HTTP Request

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I want to make a singup function to get a token.
Function should work like that:

1. First I have to make a HTTP POST request passing login value to get "nonce" string
2. Second, after first is done, when I have already "nonce" string,  I have to make another HTTP POST request with login value and password encrypted like `SHA256(SHA256(password) + nonce))`

I have a singup ractive form, and my on click button "onLogin" function use a service "singup(login, password)" function which return an observable to check if requests are done well (or not).

So I wonder how to properly implement sequence of requests to return to onLogin() function information (as observable) if one the one of them (requests) failed (i want to know if getNonce or login return error).

**Auth Service:**

```
  singup(login: string, password: string) {
    return this.getNonce(login).subscribe(result => {
      const nonce = result.nonce; 
      return this.login(login, password, nonce); 
    });
  };

  login(login: string, password: string, nonce: string | undefined): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.config.url}/user/login`, {
      login: login,
      password: sha256(sha256(password) + nonce)
    });
  };

  getNonce(login: string) {
    return this.http.post<{ nonce: string }>(`${this.config.url}/user/login`, {
      login: login
    });
  }
```

**FormClass**

```
onLogin() {
    this.authService.singup(this.singupForm.value.login, this.singupForm.value.password).subscribe(result => {
      // steps after get token or not
    });
  }
```

I will be thankful for good advices.

Answer (score 2):

To add on @wadie's suggestion (and correct answer), the reason why you should use [`switchMap()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap) (you could also use [`concatMap()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/concatMap), they'd both work) is because it turns both Observables into a single one - it's what's called a [Higher-order Observable](https://rxjs.dev/guide/higher-order-observables). This Observable will emit values or errors from any of the inner Observables, which is what you want to achieve. This will also mean that you'll only need to `subscribe()` once for the entire Observable chain.

Also, your current code shouldn't work - `login()` is called inside `signup()`, but the login request will not fire because Observables are not "activated" until you `subscribe()`, and you don't `subscribe()` to `login()`. You could indeed call `subscribe()` inside that other `subscribe()`, but then you wouldn't be able to clean that `Subscription` easily. Higher-order Observable solve that by combining the subscriptions to all the inner Observables into a single one.

Comment: Thank you for your additional explanation, it shows me that I must learn more about pipes and maps :)